# webapp script to queue up until the formula in google sheet has done

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this table :

[image]

It's a revision table where i put the revision notes of every single shots-ID. Col A is the shots-ID and there will be about 700 items. **Col K (REVNUM)** is the number of revision has been inserted - This is special column, i will use this as **a tracker** in google script. From Col N until the end column will be reserved for the revision notes. Every revision will have version: V01, V02 etc. For example , we can see in the image, the first row, has 3 revisions : V01,V02,V03.

I created a webapp (interface) using google script for user to input the data :

[image]

So when user press submit, it will insert the new revision/review to the proper cell. To find which column should it enter the value to, i use the **column K (REVNUM)** to track. In the example image , the new data should go to V04 (column Q).

Everythig is working fine. But there's one thing that bug me. If i press 'submit' twice or more in a short time, the second submit will not go to v05 but will overwrite first submit in v04. This won't happen if i do 2nd submit quite a while after the 1st one. For example if i do 2nd submit 10 second after the 1st one, everything will works just fine.

If i do 2nd sumbit , 2 second after the 1st one, it will overwrite previus submit. I found out that when i do the 1st submit, data is inserted into v04, the column K will need time to calculate the new REVNUM. But the formula in col K hasn't finished to update the REVNUM when the 2nd submit is executed, so 2nd submit will track using previous REVNUM which already expired/obsolete.

Is there any method to make the 2nd submit to queue up , to wait until all the formula is done calculated ? or is there any other better method rather than using column K as tracker  ?

EDIT :

Links to script and sheet :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_IEcXHCrhqmZrhU0mzwUx2NMfDkPaM13g1-T-E58d6s/edit?usp=sharing

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('REVIEW');
}

function submitRevision(shotid,revision){
  var ssid = "1_IEcXHCrhqmZrhU0mzwUx2NMfDkPaM13g1-T-E58d6s";
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
  var Sheet = SS.getSheetByName("rev");
  var datanum = Sheet.getRange("B3").getValue();
  var firstrow = Sheet.getRange("B4").getValue();
  var rmvcol = Sheet.getRange("D1").getValue();
  var revcol = Sheet.getRange("D2").getValue();
  var revidlist = Sheet.getRange(firstrow,1,datanum,1).getValues();
  var revrmvlist = Sheet.getRange(firstrow,rmvcol,datanum,1).getValues();
  var revdict = {};
  for (i=0;i<datanum;i++){
    revdict[revidlist[i][0]] = new Array(2);
    revdict[revidlist[i][0]] = [ i , revrmvlist[i][0]];
  }

  for (var key in revdict){
    if ( key == shotid){
      var revrow = firstrow + revdict[key][0];
      var lastrevision = revdict[key][1];
      break;
    } 
  }

  Sheet.getRange(revrow, revcol + lastrevision,1,1).setValue(revision);


}
```

**REVIEW.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <br><br>
    Shots ID :
    <select  id="select">
        <option>GOL_101_019_010</option>
        <option>GOL_101_019_020</option>
        <option>GOL_101_019_030</option>
        <option>GOL_101_019_040</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    Reviews :
    <form>
        <textarea rows="20" cols="40" id="revision"></textarea><br>
        <button type="button" onClick="addRevision()"> SUBMIT </button>
    </form>

    <script>
        function addRevision() {
            var revision = document.getElementById("revision").value;
            var shotid = document.getElementById("select").value;
            google.script.run.submitRevision(shotid, revision);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

NOTE that i've simplified everything. So in this case, the formula in column K won't have delay which cause the 'overwrite' problem. But in my real project , there are lots of script that cause delay and make the 'overwrite' problem.

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: If by chance you are you using google.script.run to do the submit then disable the submit button when you push and reenable it with a return to successhandler.

Comment: @Cooper Hi sorry , i just updated my post to include the links. I simplify it's a lot faster to execute the formula , you won't see overlap. But in real project , there are a lot of script used so it has delay that cause the 'overwrite' problem

Answer (score 1):

If the webapp form is only use by 1 user simultaneously, you can solve the problem by simply disabling the submit button until the process is done as suggested by Cooper.

If multply users may use it simultaneously, you should consider to use [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock) to ensure all submits are processed sequentially.

---

Update:

[appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) would be handled in sequence.

1. Using [appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) to save the submit in another sheet `Submit`.
2. Insert the values by formulas may be an easier approach?

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Submit!B:B,Submit!A:A=A10))
```

Comment: Thanks i will have a look at that link. Btw, i've just updated my post with the simplified script links.

Comment: Updated. Please check for your reference.

Comment: I tested appedRow(), works only if my sheet doesn't have lot of script or doesn't have heavy processing. For example in empty spreadhseet, it just capture everything. But in my real project, lot of script, some input still overwriting the previous one. For example : If i click the button 12 times fast, i only see 4 row or less inserted into the table .

Comment: Is it executed 12 times? Do you have the errors?

Comment: i modified it so i now i made 5 button, every button will write different data to sheet. I  also combined with 'disabling' button using withSuccessHandler(). So button will be disabled and will enable after success. I use appendRow() . Now i just press every single button : i press 10x ( 2x for each button ). In a fresh empty spreadsheet, i got 10 rows as i expected. But in my heavy sheet, I only got 2 or 3 row. I put the browser side by side to see the effect. i can see in my sheet, in a row is overwriten in real time along the process. It's changing value in the same cell.

Comment: But most of the time i got error :Service Spreadsheets timed out.

Comment: How long was the execution time of the failed runs? I cannot figure out a solution with the information provided. You may need to try LockService.

Comment: I made a video of it and actually want to post another question about it , but i'm not allowed to ask more question for today (quota limit for asking question) . But if you want to see it , this time 1 example without the error , pls check it out : https://youtu.be/25Kjzk-yjYI

Comment: I will post a new question and attach the script tomorrow whenever i can post question again.

Comment: Thank you for the video. Could you please quote the `appendRow` section of the script in your 'heavy script'? I want to make sure nothing wrong in there. Besides, you may consider to 'link/sync' the `disabled` of all the buttons - although it only prevents multiple submit, before writing ends, from the same user.

Comment: I made a new post here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68610714/appendrow-is-not-reliable-overwrite-existing-value-row-in-heavy-spreadsheet