# appendRow() is not reliable (overwrite existing value/row in 'heavy' spreadsheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, event-handling

I put the video link down below to explain the case. I have apps script that will write data to a google sheet. I have some buttons that will send data to google sheet whenever i press it. I use appendRow() method to add data to the table/sheet. I disable the button after every single click and use withSuccessHandler() to re-enabled the button (as seen in the video).

In my spreadsheet , i use lot of conditional formatting and lot of formula (i refer this as 'heavy' spreadsheet). When i use appendRow() some data are overwriting the previous one. I suspect this to happen because  in the 'heavy' sheet, when the first data is inserted , it takes quite a while to return the information (token) about the last row position and before the 'last row' information is ready , the next data is already coming and will eventually replace/overwrite the previous data.

It will have no problem when i use spreadsheet without many formulas. Is this a bug ? or did i make something wrong?

video link :
https://youtu.be/25Kjzk-yjYI

**code.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('UPLOAD');
}

function submitUpload(shotid){
  Logger.log(shotid);
  var ssid = "1EgFPSz2IoJDc1HfU9G2iX_PmwXMgBvY-M8YcsQfsTMQ"; // temp sheet
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
  var Usheet = SS.getSheetByName("UPLOADSTACK");  
  Usheet.appendRow([shotid]);
}
```

**UPLOAD.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="buttoncontainer"></div>
    <script>
        function upload(val) {
            document.getElementById("button_" + val).disabled = true;
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function () {
                document.getElementById("button_" + val).disabled = false;
            }).submitUpload(val);
        }

        var buttoncontainer = document.getElementById("buttoncontainer");
        values = ["GOL_101_019_010", "GOL_101_019_020", "GOL_101_019_030", "GOL_101_019_040", "GOL_101_019_050"];
        for (const val of values) {
            var button = document.createElement("button");
            button.id = "button_" + val;
            button.addEventListener("click", function () {
                upload(val);
            });
            button.textContent = val;
            buttoncontainer.appendChild(button);
            buttoncontainer.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<br><br>");
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your appendRow, you can use SpreadsheetApp.flush() to apply all pending changes:

```
  Usheet.appendRow([shotid]);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

I would also recommend using LockService.  A description of what it does -

> This service allows scripts to prevent concurrent access to sections
> of code. This can be useful when you have multiple users or processes
> modifying a shared resource and want to prevent collisions.

So your final submitUpload function would look like this (modify your return error message as needed):

```
function submitUpload(shotid){
  Logger.log(shotid);
  var ssid = "1EgFPSz2IoJDc1HfU9G2iX_PmwXMgBvY-M8YcsQfsTMQ"; // temp sheet
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
  var Usheet = SS.getSheetByName("UPLOADSTACK");  

  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  try {
      lock.waitLock(30000);
  } catch (e) {
      Logger.log('Could not obtain lock after 30 seconds');
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<b>Server busy, please try again later <p>");
  } 

  Usheet.appendRow([shotid]);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  lock.releaseLock();    
}
```